# How to find a scientific review of a theme?

Tags: publications, review-articles

I'm trying to search for a scientific review article of determined theme. That is, I'm not searching a single scientific article containing an analysis of a determined theme, I'm trying to search a scientific article containing a review of many articles about the theme and its conclusion.

What are the terms which I should include in my search (using Google)? Example: "free trade revision", or "free trade paper review"... what are the recommended terms for this search?

Extra question: What are the best sites to search about this? (scientific reviews, scientific articles, papers, books, etc..)

Note: I think my English is legible, I'm brazilian.

Comment: Google Scholar: the name of the field + review. Maybe it will be a good idea to limit it to the past few years. Also, read recent papers in the field. Reviews are commonly cited in the introduction.

Comment: In chemistry we've publications entitled like "current topics of..." or even journals like "Chemical Reviews".  Thomson-Reuter's  "Web of Science" many university libraries subscribe is an interdisciplinary database (STEM and social sciences) where key word-based search may be narrowed by publication type "review" instead of "article".

Comment: http://www.annualreviews.org is usually a good start, if you are seeking comprehensive reviews on well-established themes. Unlike highly specialized reviews, those reviews are well accessible to people of different fields, and put different work into context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest option is to use Scopus (if your University has access) and in the title, abstract, etc, fields type your keywords and in the document type field just select "Review".

Answer (score 0):

You can search it in the Google and use "main title of your interest" +"review" in your search.

Google scholar also is an aletrnative way to get the result after searching in google main site.

The third alternative is to search in journals in your field devoted to the surveys and review papers e.g. http://www.nowpublishers.com/MAL or http://www.journals.elsevier.com/computer-science-review in computer science.

Also see the recent published textbook to find probable context of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

You may look into meta-analysis:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis